# Simple sl4j logging with struts2 not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, struts2, slf4j

I am starting new with Struts2. Using sl4j for logging in HelloWorld example. No log file is created and nothing in console.

***Someone help me what I am doing wrong?***

**Below is my project structure.**

[image: Logging]

**Properties File**

```
# Default Logging Level is DEBUG. levels: DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL OR ALL. Its only appender to FILE.

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger = ALL, FILE, stdout

# Define the file appender
# log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

# backup the log files when they reach a certain size
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:\\test.log

# Specify the log file size and max backup index.
log4j.appender.Logger.MaxFileSize=5mb
log4j.appender.Logger.MaxBackupIndex=20

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=DEBUG

# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# log4j.rootLogger = ALL, FILE, stdout
# Output To Console: Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**Strust.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="HelloWorld" class="vaannila.HelloWorld">
            <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: But is the example working? What error does the red exclamation show? Clean the project if it's something related with the libraries.

Comment: @pigueiras, Project working. Red arrows just to show required jars are added. Problem is: Log file is not created and I don't see any logs in console which should be generated by <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />?.

Comment: I don't really see nothing wrong. And `devMode` has nothing to do with the log. What server are you using? Eclipse plugin for tomcat 7?

Comment: Where do you use log4j Logger in HelloWorld? I suppose log file may not be created while log4j system is not used/initiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need three jars in the deployed app's classpath, which for the WAR is WEB-INF/lib.  You need:

1. The slf4j interfaces that your code uses when logging
2. An actual logging framework that does the logging
3. The "binding" of that underlying framework to those slf4j interfaces

These things map, respectively, the following 3 jars, assuming log4j 1.2.x as the underlying framework.

1. slf4j-log4j12.jar
2. slf4j-api.jar
3. log4j12.jar

Also note that the slf4j documentation is thorough and to the point.

http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html